# Thermodynamics for math majors

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, partial-differential-equations, physics

I'm about to wrap a course in partial differential equations. We've discussed the heat/wave equations and introductory Fourier Analysis.

I'd like to do some reading into the field of thermodynamics. Would it be best to start with an introductory text given to most lower-division under graduates or should I begin with something with a little more meat on the bones? By meat on the bones, I mean a bit more rigor and explanation for the fundamental theorems and applications. If this is not clear enough please ask for clarification, I'll be glad to provide it.

Comment: What is your background on physics? Or rather to say, the research problems you have encountered involve what equations in thermodynamics?

Comment: This is probably not what you're looking for. But I recomend "[The Refrigerator and the Universe](http://www.amazon.com/The-Refrigerator-Universe-Understanding-Energy/dp/0674753259)", Goldstein and Goldstein for an overview of the field (written for the layman).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a solid basis in mathematics, I would go immediately for an advanced book on statistical mechanics. Most of the introductory classes on thermodynamics are very phenomenological and they introduce a lot of math to the math-deprived physicists (been there, done that). Besides, statistical mechanics lies a solid foundations for the more historically motivated thermodynamics. I myself used the book "Introduction to modern statistical mechanics"  by D. Chandler, which is a bit old-fashioned, but rather formal and thorough. Good luck with this wonderful field!

Comment: The text comes highly recommended on Amazon.com. I'm not certain of my solid basis in mathematics. I've yet to take an introductory course in statistics and probability. This text would indeed follow along with or follow altogether such a course. [EDIT] By course I mean, of course, probability and statistics.

Comment: @Brady Classical thermodynamics are charged with mathematical formalism, way before statistical mechanics are introduced. You should take a look to Callen's _Thermodynamics and an Introduction to Thermostatistics_. If you go straight to statistical mechanics, you'll be missing a lot on the subject. I don't know what kind of courses are taught around the world, but to assume that physicists are math-deprived is, for the most part, a nonsense.

Comment: @Pragabhava I didn't mean anything bad by saying physicists are math-deprived. I myself took a course on thermodynamics as a second-year applied physics student. I had a lot of difficulties appreciating the concepts because of my lack of math. Can you assume a second-year physics student to know the real background of a Legendre transform, for instance?

Comment: @Brady don't get discouraged to easily. The book will introduce the necessary statistical concepts along the way. Just try to read the first few chapters and see how far you get!

Answer (score 4):

I haven't been through it with a fine-toothed comb , but you might check out David R. Owen's *A First Course in the Mathematical Foundations of Thermodynamics* in the Springer Undergraduate Text in Math series.

Comment: I'm hesitant to commit to a text with no insight into its content. Amazon.com shows no reviews and you yourself are spare on its internals. Would you please provide more information as to why you recommend this text?

Comment: I'd recommend you try your college library and see if it's there, rather than committing to buying it. I took thermodynamics both freshman and senior years of college and absolutely loved the material. This book couches it all in more rigorous mathematical terminology and uses basic undergraduate mathematics background. [I should comment that thermodynamics is all about line integrals and understanding when you have path independence and when you don't. *State variables* (like energy and enthalpy) arise from path independence, whereas heat and work are path dependent.]

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion Thermodynamics is physics, chemistry and engineering.
In thermodynamics  mathematical operations are used that are unwarranted and would not be acceptable anywhere else. (eg applying a Legendre transform, without solving the differential equation involved.) I would start with 'Cengel and Boles' not with Callen.
As Gibbs noted:  "A mathematician may say anything, but a physicist must be partially sane."